# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with jvm

Tags: java, file, jvm, out-of-memory

Scenario: 
I have to read a text file with 100Mb data, but my Jvm size is-Xmx50m.
Without increasing the Jvm size , How to read the file data?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wCgF.png)